# How to clear data between first and last row in excel column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to clear data between first cell and last cell
in a excel column. I tried this code, but it deletes the data from the entire sheet, I need only for a specific column.

```
Sub DeleteRow()
Dim i1 As Long
Dim iMax As Long
iMax = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

For i1 = iMax - 1 To 2 Step - 1
    Rows(i1).EntireRow.Clear
Next i1

End Sub
```

Comment: hi.  just define the range and clear, like  Range("C2:C4").ClearContents

Comment: Does `columns(#).clearcontents` not fulfill this?  first row to last row in a column is all of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would clear content between the first row and the last row in column A.

```
Sub ClearRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2:A" & lastRow - 1).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work, still it clears entire sheet. Maybe i was not very clear, sorry for that, I need the code to clear data between first cell and last in a specific column, the data in first cell and the last must stay, the last cell position may variate.